# wrapping text around an image not working

Tags: css, xhtml

As the title says trying to make text wrap around image... don't know why it's not working, currently have :

```
.flagimages{
    position: relative; 
    left:6px;
    top:200px;
}
.flagimages img{
    background-image:url("imagelink.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    right:20px;
    top:20px;
}
```

If anyone could please indicate me where I'm going wrong, keep in mind this is assessed work =  )

Comment: `position:absolute;` with `float:right;`?

Comment: Can you share your markup?

Comment: you are using `.flagimages img` in this scenario `img` is class or HTML TAG?

Comment: Try to this http://jsfiddle.net/56g7d/1/

Used to this css --->  .flagimages{
position: relative; 
    margin-left:6;
    margin-top:200px;
}
.flagimages img{
background-image:url("imagelink.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:absolute;
right:20px;
top:20px;
  }

Comment: nope =[] =[] =[]doesn't work @rohit azad

Comment: As Mr Alien says, the image has `position:absolute`, and that is the answer. The div has nothing to float around.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/4za73/)

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flagimages{
   float: right;
}
.flagimages img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}
.clearme {
    clear: left;
}
```